# Is it ever true that the identity $E(\frac{1}{X^2}) = \frac{1}{E(X^2)}$ holds for a nontrivial random variable X?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, ratio

Is it ever true that the identity $E(\frac{1}{X^2}) = \frac{1}{E(X^2)}$ holds for a nontrivial random variable X?

I see that it would work if $X$ is a constant $1$ because $\frac{1}{1^2} = \frac{1}{1^2}$, but I assume this is the trivial solution. If I put in something like $N(0,1)$, then it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: No. $1/x$ is a strictly convex function for $x>0$, so equality would imply that $X$ is constant a.s.

Comment: @saulspatz It would only mean that the LHS is $\infty$. It does not mean that the RHS is $\infty$: for that, you need $E(X^2)=0$, i.e. $\Pr(X=0)=1$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Oh, duh

Comment: This equality is also satisfied if $X$ takes only two values, $r$ and $-r$, with probability $1$. Professor Vector's argument actually shows that $X^2$ is constant (not $X$), so this possibility exists, and it is the only one.